# cut.POSIXt: Why isn't POSIXct a date-time object?

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

(*I've read many similar problems, but could not find an answer to my problem, even though it seems trivial; I just don't see the cause of the problem*)

I have time-stamped measurements (with some offset-based numeric timestamps), and I want to aggregate at different time intervals for analysis. For readability I converted the time stamps to human-readable ones (using `as.POSIXlt()` with `origin` and `tz="UTC"` parameters).

On integer values `cut()` worked well, but I don't get it working for `POSIXlt` values. According to the manual (and some answers I found), it should work out-of-the-box.

```
Browse[1]> str(cols$time)
List of 39531
 $ : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2016-07-05 00:00:58"
 $ : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2016-07-05 00:02:02"
 $ : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2016-07-05 00:03:06"
 $ : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2016-07-05 00:04:10"
 $ : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2016-07-05 00:05:14"
 $ : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2016-07-05 00:06:18"
[...]
 $ : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2016-07-05 01:44:26"
 $ : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2016-07-05 01:45:30"
  [list output truncated]
Browse[1]> cut(cols$time, breaks="5 min")
Fehler in cut.default(cols$time, breaks = "5 min") : 
  'x' muss numerisch sein
Browse[1]> cut.POSIXt(cols$time, breaks="5 min")
Fehler in cut.POSIXt(cols$time, breaks = "5 min") : 
  'x' muss ein date-time Objekt sein
Browse[1]>
```

(*Sorry for the German locale (and error messages*))
I want R to subdivide the total time interval into either `n` equally long intervals, or intervals of a specific duration.

**Additional Info:**

I wrote this helper function (actually the maths are a bit more complicated, but the principle is this):

```
POSIX <- function(day, offset) {
    origin <- "1970-01-01 00:00:00"
    return(as.POSIXlt(day * 86400 + offset, origin=origin, tz="UTC"))
}
```

(Receives *day number* and *offset* within day, returning a `POSIXlt` timestamp)

The final timestamps themselves are created in a two-way process:

```
for (d in dayLevels) {
    days[[d]] <- POSIX(as.numeric(d), 0)
}

cols$time <- lapply(1:rows, function(i) return(cols$day[[i]] + cols$time[i])
```

(I'm adding fractional seconds to the `POSIXlt`)

Comment: Your problem is how you create `cols$time`. It should be a vector but is a list of single POSIX**c**t (not POSIX**l**t) values. Show us how you create it.

Comment: I wanted to keep the question small and simple. I was hoping one could explain me how to convert it to the correct format (I tried about everything I could imagine, with the same result all the time). Anyway I'll update the question in a moment.